# Trouble uploading file to a specific folder on Google Drive

Tags: python, file-upload, google-api, google-drive-api

I've got this method:

```
def uploadFile(filename, folderId, filepath, mimetype):
  file_metadata= {'name':filename, "parents": [{"id": folderId, "kind":"drive#file"}]}
  media = MediaFileUpload(filepath, mimetype=mimetype)
  file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
```

But it always uploads the file to the root folder of my Google Drive.
I want the file to be uploaded to a specific folder which I specify by its ID. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to upload a file in the specific folder on Google Drive using Drive API v3 with Python.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
file_metadata= {'name':filename, "parents": [{"id": folderId, "kind":"drive#file"}]}
```

#### To:

```
file_metadata = {'name': filename, "parents": [folderId], "kind": "drive#file"}
```

#### Reference:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, that's the answer I was looking for and now I feel dumb for butchering the syntax :) Thanks for help!

Comment: @Don Andre Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.